# How can I use different dynamic slug url for same component React js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have common details view in my react app.
Right now my detail view URL is like that

> blog-details/:blogId

But I want to change the URL like this

> host.com/{blog-title}/{blog-type}/{blog-id}

how can I do it?
I'm using react-router and I want to use single details to view component with a different dynamic URL slug.

Comment: Provide an updated `path="/:blogTitle/:blogType/:blogId"` prop, something like this? Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example of your attempt.

Comment: @DrewReese it's going to be work cz every time the blog title and other things are different?

Comment: Work to change your code to handle the routes/paths you want it to? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can specify some route to a component like this :

```
 <Route
    exact
    path={[
      "/:title",
      "/:title/:type",
      "/:title/:type/:id",
    ]}
    component={Blog}
  />
```

Comment: how did you get that? do you have any docs?

Comment: @RohanDevaki https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route/path-string-string

Comment: How can we do that in react router v6 ? it doesnt accept array in Path property

Comment: You should make another question i think.